# reading numy array from GCS into spark

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have 100 npz files containing numpy arrays in google storage.
I have setup dataproc with jupyter and I am trying to read all the numpy arrays into spark RDD. What is the best way to load the numpy arrays from a google storage into pyspark? 
Is there an easy way like `np.load("gs://path/to/array.npz")` to load the numpy array and then do `sc.parallelize` on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan to scale eventually you'll want to use the distributed input methods in `SparkContext` rather than doing any local file loading from the driver program relying on `sc.parallelize`. It sounds like you need to read each of the files intact though, so in your case you want:

```
npz_rdd = sc.binaryFiles("gs://path/to/directory/containing/files/")
```

Or you can also specify single files if you want, but then you just have an RDD with a single element:

```
npz_rdd = sc.binaryFiles("gs://path/to/directory/containing/files/arr1.npz")
```

Then each record is a pair of `<filename>,<str of bytes>`. On Dataproc, `sc.binaryFiles` will just automatically work directly with GCS paths, unlike `np.load` which requires local filesystem paths.

Then in your worker code, you just need to use `StringIO` to use those byte strings as the file object you put into `np.load`:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
# For example, to create an RDD of the 'arr_0' element of each of the picked objects:
npz_rdd.map(lambda l: numpy.load(StringIO(l[1]))['arr_0'])
```

During development if you really want to just read the files into your main driver program, you can always collapse your RDD down using `collect()` to retrieve it locally:

```
npz_rdd = sc.binaryFiles("gs://path/to/directory/containing/files/arr1.npz")
local_bytes = npz_rdd.collect()[0][1]
local_np_obj = np.load(StringIO(local_bytes))
```